# How can I accentuate words in Fortran and print to the screen without errors?

Tags: encoding, fortran, diacritics

In C, when we want to print an accented word, as in the Portuguese language, we use the library `locale.h` and the command `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese")` so that the output is printed on the screen correctly. As an example, I present the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    printf("\n\tA maçã caiu na cebeça dele! É a gravidade.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

returning the following message:

```
A maça caiu na cebeça dele! É a gravidade.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.350 s
Press any key to continue.
```

On the other hand, when I do the same for Fortran, i.e.,

```
program hello
    implicit none
    
    print *, "A maçã caiu na cebeça dele! É a gravidade."

end program
```

I obtain:

```
 A maτπ caiu na cebeτa dele! ╔ a gravidade.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.206 s
Press any key to continue.
```

This occurs because, unlike C, I don't know a mechanism for Fortran like the one provided by the `locale.h` library in the C language.

Given this, I ask: **How can I do the analog treatment in Fortran? Is this possible?**

**Remark**:  I am using MSYS2 MinGW64 (gfortran) on Windows with Code::Blocks and CLion (plugin Fortran).

Comment: Your code prints " A maçã caiu na cebeça dele! É a gravidade." for me. However, the behaviour is system-dependent. You have to tell us your operating system and your compiler version. On my Linux with gfortran I have no problem printing even stuff like "ⰒⰓⰑⰃⰎⰀⰔⰟ" in UTF-8. You can also try USC4 strings.

Comment: I am using MSYS2 MinGW64 (gfortran) on Windows with Code::Blocks and CLion (plugin Fortran).

Comment: Could you write minimal code with your solution as an example? Thus, I would appreciate your solution more properly.

Comment: There is no solution I would do. I just compiled your code and it worked as is. When the environment is properly configured, that is.

Comment: That said, you could also try to call `setlocale()` from Linux using a `bind(C)` interface. But I cannot test whether it helps, because your code just works by default for me.

Comment: A simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'ç ã É'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'cp437')` returns `'τ π ╔'`. Change the terminal encoding…